# Why is "><" valid criterion?

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I was trying to find a formula to count the number of values in a row. The row's cells all have formulas in them that return blank if a word cant be split up further.
I was trying random things because what I tried originally didn't work, so I tried `=countif(H2:2, "><")`, and it worked (it gave me the correct number of values, as opposed to the number of cells that contain a formula). My question is why? To me, "count if it is greater than less than" doesn't make sense. Maybe I'm reading it and/or understanding it wrong (I must be if its working). Does anyone know why this does work?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what's going on is that it's evaluating whether the values in row 2 there, in this case the letters of the word "dinosaur" are all GREATER than the value of the "less than" sign.  If you do =CODE("<") you'll see that the character code associated with "<" is 60.  If you do =CODE("d") or CODE("i") or =CODE("n") etc, you'll see that each of those letters has a code HIGHER than 60, thus it's returning 8.

If you were to replace the "n" with say, a period "." you should see the count drop to 7 since a period is "less than" a "<".

The more traditional way to count non empty cells in a row is with the "not equal to [blank]" concept like this:

```
=COUNTIF(H2:2,"<>")
```

Comment: I did try `=COUNTIF(H2:2,"<>")`, but it did not work for whatever reason, and just returned `25`, the number of cells included in the evaluation, which is why I went on to look for a different solution, thus finding "><". Thank you for the explanation!